# Can I mine Obsidian/Hellstone pre-Hardmode without getting Crimtane/Demonite Ore?

Tags: terraria

As far as I can tell, obsidian and hellstone can only be mined by the [Molten Pickaxe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Molten_Pickaxe) or the [Deathbringer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Deathbringer_Pickaxe)/[Nightmare Pickaxe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nightmare_Pickaxe).

I'm at a stage where I've explored a lot of the map, but have not ventured too deep into Crimson (and I want to stall that until I am stronger). I'd like to try my hand at mining hellstone/obsidian, but for that I need the correct pickaxe

The molten pickaxe needs hellstone to make it so that's out of the question.

The Deathbringer needs Crimtane bars. I can get these by fighting the Eye of Cthulhu, but I'm not finding many Suspicious Eyes to summon it with (and its not dropping much ore when I do manage to kill it).

Is there an easier way of getting to hellstone? Preferably without having to go through the Crimtane ore?

Comment: I'm afraid not. There are some super tiny crimtane/demonite deposits strewn around in the world though.It'll probably be easier to just dig/build a tunnel towards the ore in the crimson/curruption though. I'm not certain if there isn't another way since one of the later patches though. So this is just a comment.

Comment: Just a thought: doesn't the Eater of Worlds drop more ore than the Eye of Cthuhlu? Also, I feel like it was easier to gather the ingredients for the Worm Food, as they don't depend on the phase of the day and can be farmed.

Comment: If you're trying to get into the underworld without first completing the Crimson (AND the dungeon AND the jungle), you are in for a world of hurt. The underworld enemies are the hardest pre-hardmode enemies in the game, and they will do a lot of damage if you don't have at least crimson armor.

Comment: @Kevin ah, I see. My aim was to explore a bit and collect stuff before fighting all the bosses, but yeah, it's hard to survive in the Underworld.

Comment: @Manishearth Yeah, the thing about Terraria is that until late hardmode, there's a definite order you're expected to visit each area in. Unfortunately, you're best bet is to take out the Eater of Worlds, then immediately beat Skeletron and complete the dungeon. Good luck!

Comment: I happened to overcome this in a better way.

I found a Starfury while exploring the sky islands, and was able to get much better at defeating the Eye. Still, one needs Tissue samples to make most Crimson items. I lost to the Brain twice, though that gave me enough tissue to make a pickaxe and an armor set. I came back with a space gun and was able to easily defeat it (3 times in a row, actually).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, it is not possible to obtain hellstone without having demonite/crimtane ore.** The demonite/crimtane tier pickaxe is the only way to obtain hellstone. Additionally, the enemies in hell are a lot more dangerous than those found in the corruption/crimson.

Since you said you've beaten the Eye of Cthulhu, you should have access to the Dryad. Buy some purification powder from her, and tunnel down near the edge of the crimson/corruption biome. This allows you to the safety of your own tunnel to smash some orbs/hearts. The first orb/heart you break contains a gun (Musket/Undertaker), which is more than capable to deal with any corruption/crimson enemies. Be careful to only smash two orbs/hearts; if you smash a third, it automatically summons the boss.

In prior playthroughs without access to the Dryad, I've gotten grenades/bombs from pots to trigger the arrival of the demolitionist, purchased bombs, then combined them with gel (sticky bombs) to make it easier to tunnel sideways into the corruption/crimson. This allowed me to obtain a gun in the relative safety of my own tunnel that I can easily wall off.

Answer (score 6):

Gigazelle's answer would have been correct before 2014-05-08 and the arrival of Terraria 1.2.4 .

---

### Behold the [Reaver Shark](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Reaver_Shark)!

You need only to have attracted only a [Merchant](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Merchant) and it will mine out anything up through the 1st tier Hard Mode ores.

1. Purchase a [Bug Net](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bug_Net).
2. Catch some bait.
3. Build a Fishing Pole.
4. Visit the Ocean and fish for the only pick-axe upgrade you'll need before Hard Mode!

Comment: obsidian can be breaked with bombs, and hellstone can be bombed in hardmode

Comment: This answer was correct in version 1.2 but no longer works in 1.4, where the reaver shark no longer works to mine hellstone or obsidian. Also, worms or better bait (25%) are needed to fish reaver shark; 100 grasshoppers got me only multiple sawtooth sharks from ocean.