# How can I mine Crimstone/Ebonstone if I can't make a Deathbringer/Nightmare pickaxe?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I'm trying to obtain Crimstone but I can't because I need a Nightmare or Deathbringer pickaxe.

I need Tissue Samples to make the pickaxe. But the only way to get tissue samples is to kill Brain of Cthulhu - but to do that I need to mine the hearts underground in the biome.

How am I supposed to get tissue samples if I can't summon the brain?

I'm on the mobile version and it's up to date

Comment: Related : [Can I mine Obsidian/Hellstone pre-Hardmode without getting Crimtane/Demonite Ore?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169471/can-i-mine-obsidian-hellstone-pre-hardmode-without-getting-crimtane-demonite-ore?rq=1)

Answer (score 7):

*This is the case of **the Crimson** biome, but if you are in **the Corruption** in its stead, it is the same path of action, since apart from the appearance and name, the blocks' properties don't change.*

---

In the same fashion of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169471/can-i-mine-obsidian-hellstone-pre-hardmode-without-getting-crimtane-demonite-ore), you can't mine **Crimstone Block** prior of making a fifth tier pickaxe, for example **Deathbringer pickaxe** (**Nightmare pickaxe** for the Corruption biomes).

Thus you're right in saying that you need **Tissue Sample**, which is looted on the **Brain of Ctlulhu**. (Or **Shadow Scale** from **Eater of Worlds** in the Corruption.)

So, in order to progress, you'll have to break the **Crimson Hearts** (**Shadow Orbs** in the Corruption). Since you can't mine the Crimstone Blocks yet, you'll have to either use **Purification powder** from the Dryad on the blocks in your way to mine them, or use explosives like **Bombs** from pots or the Demolitionist which will blow them up; then you can destroy the Hearts/Orbs with a hammer or explosives.

Then you'll be able to craft the fifth tier pickaxe and progress in the game.

Comment: or use purification powder from the dryad.

Comment: @Arperum You're right, I guess I'm over aggressive with these blocks on my playthroughs!

Comment: I'm personally a big fan of the [Sticky Bomb](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sticky_Bomb).  Gotta love accurate placement.

Comment: Note that there is also a boss-summoning item for each boss. You can craft the one for the brain using bloodied spines.

Answer (score 2):

### Behold the [Reaver Shark](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Reaver_Shark)!

You need to have attracted only a [Merchant](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Merchant) and it will mine out anything up to the 1st tier Hard Mode ores.  Purchase a [Bug Net](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bug_Net), catch some bait, build a Fishing Pole, visit the Ocean, and fish for the only pick-axe upgrade you'll need before Hard Mode!

Comment: Note that according to the wiki's link, this works only for the PC version, and OP stated that he's on the mobile version, so this solution won't work for him at the moment since that hasn't been implemented on the mobile version as yet.

Comment: @Ananas, So sad.  I do appreciate my fishy tools & weapons...

Answer (score -5):

Go into underground tunnel and the tunnel is in every world ( unless you don't have the biome ) and use a hammer to mine hearts. Beware that sometimes, a meteor will land somewhere in the world sometimes when breaking the hearts. After breaking a random number of hearts, brain of cutchulu will spawn. Kill him (he spawns little eye looking minions called creepers) and he will drop tissue samples. You don't need to mine the stone to get to the hearts. There is a tunnel leading there. There. Done. My hands are tiered. Hope I was some help!